# MySQL index name and foreign key name must be different for different tables?

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

MySQL index name and foreign key name must be different for different tables?

For example,

Two tables both have the same field(profile_id) which are belonging to a third table(profiles). So I want to make the profile_id indexed and constrain it as a foreign key.

Could the index name be named "profile_id_idx" in both tables?

And "profile_id_fk" as name of foreign key for both too?

Comment: No, that's what foreign keys are for

Comment: Even if that worked, why take a risk? Just give it different names and be done with it

Answer (score 19):

Foreign Key names must be unique across all tables in all databases.  Index names may be re-used in different tables.

Comment: So explicitly naming foreign key constraints either leads to name conflicts or requires prefixing by database and table (`db_tbl_col_fk`) causing code duplication.