# Do index names have to be unique across entire database in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

For example, if I have two tables `Teacher` and `Student` that would have a column named `IDNumber`, do I have to name the indexes separately like this:

```
IDNum_teach
IDNum_stu
```

Or could I just create an index on each table for `IDNumber` and name them both `IDNum`?

Comment: I almost never name my indexes.  And there are only a few places where the name is used.  MySQL provides a name, usually the field I am indexing.  Hence I often end up with the same index name in two different tables.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338198/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes you can use same index name for both the tables.

CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX IDnum
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [index_type]

Answer (score 3):

Each table in an SQL database is essentially independent.  So, yes, you can use the same column name `IDNumber` in each table.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware that the column names can be the same, I was asking about indexes.

Comment: imagine if you had to dream up a new column name

Comment: It would be worse if column names should be unique for the whole internet =)